# GCP Proto Datastore encode JsonProperty in base64

Tags: json, python-2.7, google-app-engine, datastore, endpoints-proto-datastore

I store a blob of Json in the datastore using `JsonProperty`.
I don't know the structure of the json data.

I am using `endpoints proto datastore` in order to retrieve my data.

The probleme is the json property is encoded in base64 and I want a plain json object.

For the example, the json data will be:

```
{
    first: 1,
    second: 2
}
```

My code looks something like:

```
import endpoints
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from protorpc import remote
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel


class Model(EndpointsModel):
    data = ndb.JsonProperty()


@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', description='My Sample API')
class DataEndpoint(remote.Service):

    @Model.method(path='mymodel2', http_method='POST',
                  name='mymodel.insert')
    def MyModelInsert(self, my_model):
        my_model.data = {"first": 1, "second": 2}
        my_model.put()
        return my_model

    @Model.method(path='mymodel/{entityKey}',
                  http_method='GET',
                  name='mymodel.get')
    def getMyModel(self, model):
        print(model.data)
        return model


API = endpoints.api_server([DataEndpoint])
```

When I call the api for getting a model, I get:

```
POST /_ah/api/myapi/v1/mymodel2
{
    "data": "eyJzZWNvbmQiOiAyLCAiZmlyc3QiOiAxfQ=="
}
```

where `eyJzZWNvbmQiOiAyLCAiZmlyc3QiOiAxfQ==` is the base64 encoded of `{"second": 2, "first": 1}`

And the print statement give me: `{u'second': 2, u'first': 1}`

So, in the method, I can explore the json blob data as a python `dict`.
But, in the api call, the data is encoded in base64.

I expeted the api call to give me:

```
{
    'data': {
        'second': 2,
        'first': 1
     }
}
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: Just as a clarification, what do you expect your `data` variable to be? Is it the whole entity, or is it just a property called *data* inside your entity? Bear in mind that `JsonProperty` is a [property type used for Datastore blobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types); so if that is not your case, maybe you should use a different property type, such as `StringProperty` or `IntegerProperty`. But in order to help you further, you should define what your `data` looks like.

Comment: It is a blob data with a Json structure. I tried to define the structure with `StructureProperty`, `StringProperty` and `IntegerProperty`, but I failed because the structure contains list of list. List implies to use `repeated` option in `StruturedProperty`, but it is not allowed, for the model, to have a nested `repeated` property. I didn't try to define an endpoint `Message` with this nested repeated StructuredProperty.

Comment: Moreover, I expeted the behavour of `JsonProperty` to be plain Json when calling the API, and it is not. But in the `getMyModel` method I can log `model.data` and I see the data as a python dict. I wonder why endpoint is encoding the data object.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce your issue. Is there any reason why you would need your Python dict to be stored as `JsonProperty`? Would it be a problem for you to cast the `dict` to a `string`, store it as `StringProperty`, and then later cast again to `dict` if necessary (using [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), for example)?

Comment: Yes, I can store the `dict` in a `StringProperty`. But, it is still the same problem, the API will produce a string containing my json data. So instead of doing a base64 decoding, I will parse a json dumps to json object. The json blob data is used by the front end application, but the product owner wants a Json Api be used in future use case. I know how to create Rest Api Json with flask, but we are not allowed to use it, every thing must be done using endpoint. So, I am stuck to provide a plain json api using endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments of your question, let me share with you a sample code that you can use in order to store a JSON object in Datastore (it will be stored as a string), and later retrieve it in such a way that:

- It will show as plain JSON after the API call.
- You will be able to parse it again to a Python dict using `eval`.

I hope I understood correctly your issue, and this helps you with it.

```
import endpoints
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from protorpc import remote
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class Sample(EndpointsModel):
  column1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  column2 = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  column3 = ndb.StringProperty()

@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', description='My Sample API')
class MyApi(remote.Service):
  # URL: .../_ah/api/myapi/v1/mymodel - POSTS A NEW ENTITY
  @Sample.method(path='mymodel', http_method='GET', name='Sample.insert')
  def MyModelInsert(self, my_model):
    dict={'first':1, 'second':2}
    dict_str=str(dict)

    my_model.column1="Year"
    my_model.column2=2018
    my_model.column3=dict_str
    my_model.put()
    return my_model

  # URL: .../_ah/api/myapi/v1/mymodel/{ID} - RETRIEVES AN ENTITY BY ITS ID
  @Sample.method(request_fields=('id',), path='mymodel/{id}', http_method='GET', name='Sample.get')
  def MyModelGet(self, my_model):
    if not my_model.from_datastore:
      raise endpoints.NotFoundException('MyModel not found.')

    dict=eval(my_model.column3)
    print("This is the Python dict recovered from a string: {}".format(dict))

    return my_model

application = endpoints.api_server([MyApi], restricted=False)
```

I have tested this code using the development server, but it should work the same in production using App Engine with Endpoints and Datastore.

After querying the first endpoint, it will create a new Entity which you will be able to find in Datastore, and which contains a property `column3` with your JSON data in string format:

[image]

Then, if you use the ID of that entity to retrieve it, in your browser it will show the string without any strange encoding, just plain JSON:

[image]

And in the console, you will be able to see that this string can be converted to a Python dict (or also a JSON, using the `json` module if you prefer):

[image]

I hope I have not missed any point of what you want to achieve, but I think all the most important points are covered with this code: a property being a JSON object, store it in Datastore, retrieve it in a readable format, and being able to use it again as JSON/dict.

---

***Update:***

I think you should have a look at the [list of available Property Types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types) yourself, in order to find which one fits your requirements better. However, as an additional note, I have done a quick test working with a `StructuredProperty` (a property inside another property), by adding these modifications to the code:

```
#Define the nested model (your JSON object)
class Structured(EndpointsModel):
  first = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  second = ndb.IntegerProperty()

#Here I added a new property for simplicity; remember, StackOverflow does not write code for you :)
class Sample(EndpointsModel):
  column1 = ndb.StringProperty()
  column2 = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  column3 = ndb.StringProperty()
  column4 = ndb.StructuredProperty(Structured)

#Modify this endpoint definition to add a new property
@Sample.method(request_fields=('id',), path='mymodel/{id}', http_method='GET', name='Sample.get')
  def MyModelGet(self, my_model):
    if not my_model.from_datastore:
      raise endpoints.NotFoundException('MyModel not found.')

    #Add the new nested property here
    dict=eval(my_model.column3)
    my_model.column4=dict
    print(json.dumps(my_model.column3))
    print("This is the Python dict recovered from a string: {}".format(dict))

    return my_model
```

With these changes, the response of the call to the endpoint looks like:

[image]

Now `column4` is a JSON object itself (although it is not printed in-line, I do not think that should be a problem.

I hope this helps too. If this is not the exact behavior you want, maybe should play around with the Property Types available, but I do not think there is one type to which you can print a Python dict (or JSON object) without previously converting it to a String.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is almost what I want. In fact, by plain json I mean I can explore the json blob data without doing operation like parsing the json string.

Comment: So, from your example, I want to get `{..."column3": {second: 2, first: 1} ...}`. Note that `{second: 2, first: 1}` is not in a string.

Comment: May be, I wasn't clear enought, but in my example, I am able to print the variable `model` as a python `dict`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Have a look at it in case it helps, although I do not think there is much more that can be done with the limitations that you commented.

Comment: Ok, thanks! before seing your update, I edited my question to be more clear for other. But whatever, as you said `I do not think there is one type to which you can print a Python dict (or JSON object) without previously converting it to a String`. I think my question is resolved.

Comment: I guess then my update solves what you want to achieve, as the `column4` part of the response looks exactly like what you want to achieve as per your update on the question. I am glad I could help :)